# AccountController not redirecting to the correct page when using Active Directory authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory, ldap

I am modifying the AccountController to use a separate class that queries Active Directory for information and stores that info in the Login Model. In my account controller I have this:

```
try{
    LDAPAuth.LDAPQuery(model);
    return RedirectToAction("Homepage", "HomePage");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw new Exception(e.message);
}
```

I am surrounding it in a try/catch becasue if the DirectorySearcher did not find the user it will tell them that the username or passwrod is wrong and I am just trying to pass the exception on the view. What is happening is that when it gets inside the try block the model is set perfectly fine with the attributes I want but the redirection takes me to

```
http://localhost:7606/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fHomePage%2fHomepage
```

LDAPAuth class is implemented according to this solution, I also surrounded this in try/catch to catch invalid users which I am trying to pass to the View

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295157/how-do-i-query-activedirectory-using-ldap-with-a-username-not-a-cn
```

I am not sure what is the problem and debugging it is not helping either.

I hope somebody can help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before you redirect to action, issue a FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie. This should override the default behaviour of the return URL:

Its also worth noting that the bool in SetAuthCookie(string username, bool createPersistantCookie) can be used to remember the user. For this example I have set it to false.

```
try{
  LDAPAuth.LDAPQuery(model);
  FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
  return RedirectToAction("Homepage", "HomePage");
}
```